# "Unknown error response from the server." after creating table

Tags: google-bigquery

After creating a table in Bigquery, I get the following error: "Unknown error response from the server.". This table cannot even be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue and you can follow up the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/158236532) for further updates. The issue happens due to the request being too large for some tables with a lot of fields. Keep in mind that there is no possibility to load the preview tabs for tables with more than `1000` fields.

Sometimes it may happen that specific web browser can cause `Unknown error response from the server` issue, so I suggest to try another web browser to access the BigQuery UI.

In addition to this, you can execute the following command on Cloud Shell, to verify that you can see the table schema using the `bq cli` tool instead of the UI. If that works, it confirms that this could be a UI issue:

```
bq show \
--schema \
--format=prettyjson \
project_id:dataset.table
```

I hope you found it useful.